# Not getting req.body results in login function despite it working in the registration function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I'm currently in the process of adding authentication to my app using the MERN stack.

I've managed to add the register functionality for the backend, but I'm struggling with the login function. Despite the user existing in the database, when I test it out in Postman I get an error every time. I tried to just find the user and not validate anything, but that also throws an error, which is confusing since the email definitely exists in the database.

Here's the loginUser and registerUser functions:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require ('bcryptjs')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
let User = require('../models/user.model')

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body

    //validate

    if(!name || !email || !password) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Please add all fields")
    }

    const userExists = await User.findOne({email})

    if(userExists){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("User already exists")
    }

    //hash password

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

    //create new user

    const user = await User.create({
        name : name, 
        email : email, 
        password : hashedPassword
    })

    if (user){
        res.status(201).json({
            _id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email 
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Invalid user data")
    }
})

const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
  
    // Check for user email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
  
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      res.json({
        _id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      })
    } else {
      res.status(400)
      throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
    }
  })

const getUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    res.json("getUser")
})

router.route('/').post(registerUser)

router.route('/login').post(loginUser)

module.exports = router
```

And the Postman request:
[image]

I double checked the spellings and routes, which are all working fine, and I simply can't put my finger on why it isn't finding the User.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: to further debug it its best to identify if its the password that's invalid or if it can find the user, as both give the same error.  temporarily for debug purposes  i would either use a debugger and inspect or print to console the content of  the use variable in the "loginUser" handler.  my first thought is that findOne {email} is trying to lookup a record whose _id: is email.  and it should be something like findOne({email: email}), giving it an object with properties to match.  but i have not used mongo a lot.

Comment: Yes, so it can't find the user at all. However, user validation in registerUser does work as expected where the email is also passed, so I don't think it is that.

Comment: I would try printing out the contents of email variable to the console to check its what is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm getting undefined. But it is the same object as registerUser and that is working fine (as in req.body) is getting the parameters, so why in logUser is it undefined?

Comment: What body parsers do you have attached?

Comment: I thought body parser was included in express, so I haven't included any. I have `app.use(express.json())` in my server.js file.

Comment: It may be included in the express package (ie you don't need to install an additional package) but nonetheless, you need to activate it ...

Comment: So you have a bodyparser attached, but the wrong one. Your postman screenshot shows, you are posting a `form-data` body. That's not json.  `express.json()` will only parse JSON data ...

Comment: Right, but I've been sending data back and forth with other routes and didn't need to activate anything, so why do I need to it now? As to the form-data comment, I also tried posting raw data, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Don't know how your other requests look like ... But `express.json()` will only parse a json body (with `Content-Type: application/json` header) ...

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was Postman all along! I just assumed it would be the same headers etc. because I didn't change anything since my last successful request, but the type wasn't JSON, it was text - I changed it back to JSON and all working as expected, thanks again!